# tikz connection label and node distance

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to have `tikz` **automatically** determining the distance between two nodes based on a third node used to connect them?

For instance, in the following picture the arrow used to connect the nodes are too short. Can `tikz` calculate its length automatically so that its label fits it better?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [rectangle,draw] (a) {source program};
  \node [rectangle,draw] (b) [right=of a] {token list};
  \draw [->] (a.east) -- (b.west) node[above] {lexical analysis};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: connection too small for its label]

Comment: ... and after posting my answer, I've found the similar question I was thinking of: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20693/86

Comment: @AndrewStacey I would even say that it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I feel certain that I've answered a similar question before, but I can't find it now.)

One solution is simply to change the order in which you draw things.  Since the `token list` node's position should depend on the length of the `lexical analysis` node, draw the `lexical analysis` one first.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46842/86}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [rectangle,draw] (a) {source program};
  \node[above right] at (a.east) (l) {lexical analysis};
  \draw[->] (l.south west) -- (l.south east);
  \node [rectangle,draw,right] at (l.south east) (b) {token list};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

To put the `lexical analysis` and the `node` commands in the same command, you could write

```
 \draw[->] node [
    above right,
    append after command={
      (\tikzlastnode.south west) -- (\tikzlastnode.south east)
    }
] at (a.east) (l) {lexical analysis};
```

Result:

[image: positioning nodes in the right order]

Answer (score 7):

You can also get the length of the argument using `\pgfmathwidth` or `width` with the use of `\pgfmathparse`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [rectangle,draw] (a) {source program};
\pgfmathwidth{"Lexical Analysis"}
  \node [rectangle,draw] (b) [right= \pgfmathresult pt of a] {token list};
  \draw [->] (a.east) -- (b.west) node[midway,above] {lexical analysis};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the positioning is too tight you can further add some additional space.

Answer (score 5):

you can use an intermediate node with \ phantom as shown below to calculate the width

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [rectangle,draw] (a) {source program};
  \node[right =0em of a](ph){\phantom{lexical analysis}};
     \node [rectangle,draw] (b) [right=0em of ph] {token list};
  \draw [->] (a.east) -- (b.west) node[midway,above] {lexical analysis};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```